# создание бинарного дерева

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Пишу функции ввода/ вывода бинарного дерева
  различными методами 
Но после ввода элементов(пока не 0) ничего не происходит, помогите разобраться, в чем ошибка

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct tTree
{
    int info;
    tTree *left;
    tTree *right;
};
typedef tTree *pTree;

pTree formTree()
{
    pTree root;
    int info;
    cin>>info;
    if(info==0) return NULL;

    root=new tTree;
    root->info=info;
    root->left=formTree();
    if (!root->left)
        return nullptr;

    root->right=formTree();
    if (!root->right)
        return nullptr;

    return root;

}


void printLeft_to_Right(pTree root) //вывод слева направо
{
    if (root)
    {
        printLeft_to_Right(root->left);
        cout<<root->info;
        printLeft_to_Right(root->right);
    }
    return;
}
void printTop_Down(pTree tree) //снизу вверх
{
    if (tree)
    {
        cout<<tree->info;
        printTop_Down(tree->left);
        cout<<tree->info;
        printTop_Down(tree->right);
    }
}

void printDown_Top(pTree root) //сверху вниз
{
    if (root == NULL)   
    {
        return;
    }
    printDown_Top(root->left);   //рекурсивный вызов левого поддерева
    printDown_Top(root->right);  //рекурсивный вызов правого поддерева
    cout << root->info << " ";
}
int main ()
{
    pTree my_root = nullptr;
    my_root=formTree();
    printDown_Top(my_root);
    printTop_Down(my_tree);
    printDown_Top(my_tree);

    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: что значит "ничего не происходит"? вы вводите 0 и ваша formTree возвращает в main nullptr. Зачем вот это if (!root->left) return nullptr; и аналогичное для right?

Comment: Такой вариант не проходит, если вы об этом)
```c++ 
pTree formTree(pTree root)
{
    //    pTree root;
    int info;
    cin>>info;
    if(info==0) return NULL;
  
    root=new tTree;
    root->info=info;
    root->left=formTree(root);
    root->right=formTree(root);
    return root;

}


```

Comment: для чего вам  #include <iostream>  using namespace std; если вы пишете в стиле С?...

Comment: а чем он не подходит, какая вам вообще функциональность нужна от fromTree?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, знаю, что лучше использовать это, но пока учусь, а не работаю, позволяю себе это использовать)

Comment: @timbars, я хочу вводить элементы дерева, пока не введу 0, но это не работает. После введенного 0 не прекращается работа функции formTree